# is using an an async lambda with Task.Run() redundant?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I just came across some code like:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => { await Foo.StartAsync(); });
task.Wait();
```

(No, I don't know the inner-workings of `Foo.StartAsync()`).  My initial reaction would be to get rid of `async`/`await` and rewrite as:

```
var task = Foo.StartAsync();
task.Wait();
```

Would that be correct, or not (again, knowing nothing at all about `Foo.StartAsync()`).  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31584851/8877) answer to [What difference does it make - running an 'async' action delegate with a Task.Run ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583835/what-difference-does-it-make-running-an-async-action-delegate-with-a-task-ru)  seems to indicate there may be cases when it might make sense, but it also says "To tell the truth, I haven't seen that many scenarios ..."

Comment: In both cases you should `await` the task instead of waiting synchronously with `Task.Wait`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Normally*, the *intended* usage for `Task.Run` is to execute CPU-bound code on a non-UI thread. As such, it would be quite rare for it to be used with an `async` delegate, but it is possible (e.g., for code that has both asynchronous and CPU-bound portions).

However, that's the intended usage. I think in your example:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => { await Foo.StartAsync(); });
task.Wait();
```

It's far more likely that the original author is attempting to synchronously block on asynchronous code, and is (ab)using `Task.Run` to [avoid deadlocks common in that situation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) (as I describe on my blog).

In essence, it looks like the "thread pool hack" that I describe in my [article on brownfield asynchronous code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

The *best* solution is to not use `Task.Run` *or* `Wait`:

```
await Foo.StartAsync();
```

This will cause `async` to grow through your code base, which is the best approach, but may cause an unacceptable amount of work for your developers right now. This is presumably why your predecessor used `Task.Run(..).Wait()`.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, there are very similar design problems shared between `IDisposable` and `async`.

Answer (score 10):

Mostly yes.

Using `Task.Run` like this is mostly used by people who don't understand how to execute an async method.

However, there is a difference. Using `Task.Run` means starting the async method on a `ThreadPool` thread.

This can be useful when the async method's synchronous part (the part before the first await) is substantial and the caller wants to make sure that method isn't blocking.

This can also be used to "get out of" the current context, for example where there isn't a `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: @Dan I wouldn't say that. Also, it's less an issue for the method itself. It may be an issue for the caller. If your thread is "special" (UI thread, or waiting for requests) and you want to offload as much as you can to other threads you may use `Task.Run`.

Comment: so the recommended way should be async await inside Task.Run as well?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that's beside the question. It's not needed in this case, but it's reasonable to use it to reduce confusion. I think `Task.Run(() => Foo.StartAsync())` is clearer

Comment: @i3arnon i am still unclear when to put it and when not, ``Task.Run()`` is itself async call right?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad when to put what where? the async and await inside the `Task.Run` are never needed. `Task.Run` itself returns a task you can await.

Comment: i was talking about async and awaiit operator @i3arnon

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that your method has to be marked `async` to be able to use the `await` keyword.

The code as written seems to be a workaround for running asynchronous code in a synchronous context. While I wouldn't say you should never ever do this, using async methods is preferable in almost every scenario.

```
// use this only when running Tasks in a synchronous method
// use async instead whenever possible
var task = Task.Run(async () => await Foo.StartAsync());
task.Wait();
```

Async methods, like your example of `Foo.StartAsync()`, should always return a `Task` object. This means that using `Task.Run()` to create another task is usually redundant in an async method. The task returned by the async method can simply be awaited by using the `await` keyword. The only reason you should use `Task.Run()` is when you are performing CPU-bound work that needs to be performed on a separate thread. The task returned by the async method can simply be awaited by using the `await` keyword. You can read more in depth details in [Microsoft's guide to async programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

In an async method, your code can be as simple as:

```
await Foo.StartAsync();
```

If you want to perform some other work while the task is running, you can assign the function to a variable and `await` the result (task completion) later.

For example:

```
var task = Foo.StartAsync();
// do some other work before waiting for task to finish
Bar();
Baz();
// now wait for the task to finish executing
await task;
```

With CPU-bound work that needs to be run on a separate thread, you can use `Task.Run()`, but you `await` the result instead of using the thread blocking `Task.Wait()`:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => await Foo.StartAsync());
// do some other work before waiting for task to finish
Bar();
Baz();
// now wait for the task to finish executing
await task;
```