# Busy indicator not showing in async method

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xceed-plus-edition

I am using [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit) and [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) libraries.

I would like to implement the WPF Toolkit busy indicator and periodically informs the user with some info (binding with BusyMessage property in the viewmodel).

However, when button 'Start' is clicked, the busy indicator (IsBusy bound to IsBusy property in viewmodel) is not shown. What I am doing wrong?
Oddly enough, it works when IsBusy is set to true in the constructor of the viewmodel.

**App.xaml**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
    }
}
```

**Window**

```
<Window xmlns:xctk='http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit'
    DataContext='{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}'>
 <StackPanel>
 <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy='{Binding IsBusy}'>
  <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Margin='4'>
        <TextBlock Text='{Binding DataContext.BusyMessage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}' />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>      
<Button Content='Start ...'
        Command='{Binding StartCommand}'
        HorizontalAlignment='Center'
        VerticalAlignment='Center' />
</xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

**Viewmodel**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _busyMessage;

    public string BusyMessage
    {
        get { return _busyMessage; }
        set
        {
            if (_busyMessage != value)
            {
                _busyMessage = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(_busyMessage));
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isBusy;

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set {
            if (_isBusy != value)
            {
                _isBusy = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(_isBusy));
            }
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand StartCommand
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(() => StartExecute()); }
    }


    private async void StartExecute()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //update UI from worker thread
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => BusyMessage = "Work 1 Done");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //update UI from worker thread
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => BusyMessage = "Work 2 Done");
        });
        IsBusy = false;
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //Works when boolean is set to 'true' in constructor
        //IsBusy = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use async void outside of event handlers, as a rule of thumb; return a Task so the method can be awaited properly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void

Comment: @AlexPaven Better code should be public RelayCommand StartCommand
        {
            get { return new RelayCommand(async() => await StartExecute()); }
        }. That is correct?

Comment: async lambdas have pitfalls of their own and should be carefully researched first (in some ways they're equivalent to async void). I prefer creating a separate RelayCommand with better async support. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591462/is-using-an-an-async-lambda-with-task-run-redundant - haven't had my morning coffee tho so I might be confusing things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly why I prefer [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/docs/) - it has "busy indicator" built into ReactiveCommand, even async one.

As for your problem, I would say that your `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(_isBusy));` is wrong and it should be `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy)); // name of the public property`

Also, depending on your RaisePropertyChanged implementation, you can propably leave the argument empty and just use `RaisePropertyChanged();`