# Correctly awaiting Task.Run with async lambda expression

Tags: c#, async-await, task

so I have an async method wrapped in **Task.Run** like so:

```
//SynchronisationContext = UI Thread
await Task.Run(async => 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
       var res = ComplicatedCalulation(); //Takes about 1 second
       await ThirdPartyLib.WriteToDatabase(res);
    }
});
```

Does the **await** on the above code await the async lambda code or does it just await the `Task` being started (i.e. returning straight away)

I know with `Task.Factory.StartNew` the correct use is

`await Task.Factory.StartNew<Task>(async => await MyAsyncMethod()).Result`

Is this also true for **Task.Run**?

Comment: Maybe this (and its associated links) by *Stephen Cleary* ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591462/is-using-an-an-async-lambda-with-task-run-redundant

Comment: `Task.Result` is so seldom the right choice that I find myself questioning whether it really is the "correct use" here...

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm not sure its correct. His advise is to avoid that situation, but I think I have a valid use. I have added some context to the `Task` method

Comment: The `StartNew` example should use `Unwrap`, not `Result`. Also, I strongly recommend always passing a `TaskScheduler` to `StartNew`. Or, better yet, just use `Task.Run`, which does both of these for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will wait till the end of the compute using the task mechanism. This will not block your thread but it will not execute code beyond this point until everything in your loop is done.

```
public static async Task Test()
{
    await Task.Run(async () => 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Console.WriteLine($"inside {i}");
        }
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

will give the following output:

```
inside 0
inside 1
inside 2
inside 3
inside 4
inside 5
inside 6
inside 7
inside 8
inside 9
Done
```