# Are the await / async keywords needed under Task.Run?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have an async lambda expression wrapped under Task.Run.
However, it looks like I can drop the async and await keywords and they will produce the same result.

```
t1 = Task.Run(() => DoSomethingExpensiveAsync());
t2 = Task.Run(() => DoSomethingExpensiveAsync());
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
```

vs

```
var t1 = Task.Run(async () => await DoSomethingExpensiveAsync());
var t2 = Task.Run(async () => await DoSomethingExpensiveAsync());
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
```

1. How come the compiler let me do this and what is happening behind
   the scene?
2. Is there a situation where adding them will make a
   difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is using an an \`async\` lambda with \`Task.Run()\` redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591462/is-using-an-an-async-lambda-with-task-run-redundant)

Comment: You forgot this variation: `var t1 = Task.Run(DoSomethingExpensiveAsync);`

Comment: @JanWichelmann no the post you suggested does not answer my question. The post does not explain the technical difference. The suggested answer only tells you not to Wait an async method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come the compiler let me do this and what is happening behind the scene?

The overload of `Task.Run` that you're invoking takes a `Func<Task>` - that is, a `Task`-returning function. It doesn't matter where the `Task` comes from; the function just needs to return it from somewhere.

If you pass a delegate without `async` and `await`, then the delegate is just calling a `Task`-returning function and returns that same `Task`. If you pass a delegate with `async` and `await`, then the delegate calls the `Task`-returning function and `await`s it; the actual `Task` returned from the delegate is [created by the `async` keyword](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

In this case, the two are semantically equivalent. Using the `async`/`await` keywords are a bit less efficient, since the compiler creates a state machine for the `async` delegate.

> Is there a situation where adding them will make a difference?

[Yes](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). In the general case, you should keep `async` and `await`. Only remove them in extremely simple "passthrough" situations like the one here.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually three variants.

```
var task = Task.Run(() => DoSomethingExpensiveAsync());
```

^ This one declares a new anonymous non-async function that calls `DoSomethingExpensiveAsync()` and returns its `Task`. The compiler compiles this anonymous function and passes it as an argument to `Task.Run()`.

```
var task = Task.Run( async () => await DoSomethingExpensiveAsync() );
```

^ This one declares a new anonymous async function that calls `DoSomethingExpensiveAsync()`. It then returns an incomplete `Task`, waits for  `DoSomethingExpensiveAsync()` to finish, and then signals the task as complete.

```
var task = Task.Run(DoSomethingExpensiveAsync);
```

^ This one does not declare a new anonymous function at all. A direct reference to `DoSomethingExpensiveAsync` will be passed as an argument to `Task.Run()`.

All of these are valid because all three versions return a `Task` and therefore match the overload of `Task.Run()` that accepts a `Func<Task>`.

As a black box, all three calls will end up doing the same thing. However the first two result in a new function being compiled (although I'm not certain it wouldn't be optimized away) and the second one also results in another state machine being created for it.

The difference might be clearer if we rewrite them without using lambda expressions or anonymous functions. The following code does exactly the same thing:

```
//This is the same as Task.Run( () => DoSomethingExpensiveAsync());
Task Foo()
{
    return DoSomethingExpensiveAsync();
}
var task = Task.Run(Foo);

//This is the same as Task.Run(async () => await DoSomethingExpensiveAsync());
async Task Bar()
{
    return await DoSomethingExpensiveAsync();
}
var task = Task.Run(Bar);
```

The difference between these two is that one "elides" tasks while the other doesn't. Stephen Cleary has written a [whole blog on the subject](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Comment: Which version you choose will also influence the stack trace if `DoSomethingExpensiveAsync()` returns a Faulted task due to an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is the same as

```
t1 = DoSomethingExpensiveAsync();
t2 = DoSomethingExpensiveAsync();
await Task.WhenAll( t1, t2 );
```

because [Task.Run( Func< function )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__) will return a **proxy** of the task generated by function. There is no other Task created, and so you are awaiting the original tasks.

When you already have an async method then there is no need to use `Task.Run` at all.

Comment: You can use `Task.Run` together with `async` method if you want to get rid of original synchronization context.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing what `DoSomethingExpensiveAsync` it's impossible to tell for certain what will happen.

Let's assume `DoSomethingExpensiveAsync` is something like this:

```
async Task DoSomethingExpensiveAsync()
{
     SynchronousMethod();
     await AsynchronousMethod();
}
```

In the first snippet, `Task.Run` will schedule the invocation of `DoSomethingExpensiveAsync` to the thread pool and returns as soon as `SynchronousMethod` returns.

In the second snippet, `Task.Run` will schedule the invocation of `DoSomethingExpensiveAsync` to the thread pool and returns when the `Task` return by `DoSomethingExpensiveAsync` is completed.

Comment: How does that answer the question? The question was about why async / await can be omitted in the cases shown.