# Transforming a List into a List of Tasks with or without Task.Run?

Tags: c#, async-await

So I know Task.Run basically makes the code run in a new thread from the thread pool. But what is the difference if I do something like this:

```
var tasks = new List<string>(){ "foo", "bar" }
   .Select(e => Task.Run(async () => await Process(e)))
   .ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

vs

```
var tasks = new List<string>(){ "foo", "bar" }
   .Select(async e => await Process(e))
   .ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

My understanding would be that the second snippet only runs one at a time while it awaits some async process, and the first one actually runs them in parallel on threads from the thread pool?

Comment: You're specifying `async` but you're not doing `await` anywhere. The code will give you a build warning.

Comment: To get a good understanding, I suggest you add to your test program's `Process()` method a line of code `Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` and watch the output of both versions. The second version will give a compile warning, and will indeed be synchronous.

Comment: does this answer your question? [is using an an `async` lambda with `Task.Run()` redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591462/is-using-an-an-async-lambda-with-task-run-redundant)

Comment: @Sean I forgot to include the await. I corrected the question.

Comment: @PatrickBeynio thank you. So if the intent is to trigger parallel execution of async methods the first method would indeed be correct?

Comment: As a side note, according to the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) the `Process` method should be named `ProcessAsync`.

Comment: yes, otherwise they would still get executed after each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these approaches instantiate a list of tasks, and then `await` them to complete. Normally there should be no difference between them, unless the `ProcessAsync` method returns already completed tasks (unless it runs synchronously in other words). For example the implementation bellow:

```
async Task ProcessAsync(string arg)
{
     Thread.Sleep(1000); // Simulate some heavy calculation
     await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

...blocks the current thread for 1000 msec and then returns a completed task. This implementation will run in parallel only with the first approach (with `Task.Run`), and will run sequentially with the second approach (without `Task.Run`). The reason is that creating the task is expensive (all the work is done during the creation), and awaiting the task is cheap (the task has already been completed). With [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) you essentially offload the expensive work to the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) threads.